# How to set the default domain for a new Roundcube webmail user?

Tags: email, webmail

New Roundcube identities get a '@localhost' domain part for their Email address. That is kind of useless. I would rather have Roundcube take the Apache HTTP host (minus a possible 'www.'), since my users will use 'their' associated domain for getting to the Roundcube interface. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. In the main config of roundcube (`/var/lib/roundcube/config/main.inc.php`) you can set the `mail_domain` variable:

```
$rcmail_config['mail_domain'] = '%d';
```

There are multiple placeholders, but `%d` will use the web server domain, which is fine for me.

Comment: In the current version (1.1.3), it would be `$config['mail_domain'] = '%d';` in the file `roundcube/config/config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 4):

Look here:

```
    grep -nR -B9 mail_domain defaults.inc.php
    440-
    441-// This domain will be used to form e-mail addresses of new users
    442-// Specify an array with 'host' => 'domain' values to support multiple hosts
    443-// Supported replacement variables:
    444-// %h - user's IMAP hostname
    445-// %n - http hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    446-// %d - domain (http hostname without the first part)
    447-// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
    448-// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
    449:$config['mail_domain'] = '';
```

So, you could add

```
$config['mail_domain'] = '%d';
```

to your `roundcube/config/config.inc.php` file. (not to the `defaults.inc.php` file which may be overwritten by upgrades)

Answer (score 0):

In "WHM Home » Server Configuration » Tweak Settings", under the "Mail" tab, you can disable the other Webmail clients by ensuring the following options are not selected:

"Enable Horde Webmail"
"Enable SquirrelMail webmail"

Or you can directly login using the below URLS:

server:2095/3rdparty/roundcube/

server:2096/3rdparty/roundcube/

If proxy sub-domains are enabled, the following URLs, using the "webmail." sub-domain, will also go directly to Roundcube; replace "domain" with your cPanel account domain name:

webmail.domain:2095/3rdparty/roundcube/

webmail.domain:2096/3rdparty/roundcube/

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread but you should be able to set the server name using this command

```
dpkg-reconfigure roundcube-core
```

In my case I have isp3config, my server is set up as `debian.example.com`, my two sites are `example.com` and `example.net`.

When it asks for the server name I put in `debian.example.com`, if you leave it blank it will ask you the server on the log in page.